# Who is she to be possessed by the devil, and Who accused several local women of witchcraft?

Tags: subjects

I read this sentence and I am curious what subject is on 'After' clause.

> The infamous Salem witch trials began during the spring of 1692, **after a group of young girls in Salem Village, Massachusetts, claimed to be possessed by the devil and accused several local women of witchcraft**

I understand like this.

1. A group of young girls in Salem Village, Massachusetts was claimed to be possessed by the devil.
2. The infamous Salem witch trials accused a group of young girls of witchcraft.

I can't understand this sentence. Who is she to be possessed by the devil, and Who accused several local women of witchcraft?

Comment: You suggestion *was claimed to be possessed* is mistaken. It's not a "passive" construction (whereby ***unknown / unspecified people*** made those claims about the young girls). It's just a standard "active" construction - ***the girls themselves** made this claim (that they were possessed)*.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is knowing that state names are set off with commas *when they follow a city name*:

- Salem Village, Massachusetts, is the setting of the story.

If you remove the state (as you would do if it were a better-known city), the sentence becomes easier to parse:

> The infamous Salem witch trials began during the spring of 1692, after
> a group of young girls in Salem Village claimed to be
> possessed by the devil and accused several local women of witchcraft.

Without the state and its commas, we more easily see the “after” clause has one subject (“a ground of young girls in Salem Village”) shared by two verbs (“claimed” and “accused”).